# How to create two static libraries in which one has dependency over the other in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, static-libraries, static-linking

I am trying to create two static libraries in which one static library is dependent on the other in Xcode.
Below is a simple example that I use to demonstrate what exactly I mean:

In static library **libAnimal.a**, I will expose an Animal Object

```
@interface Animal : NSObject

-(void) eat;

@end
```

and in another static library **libDog.a**, I want to expose a Dog Object which overrides the Animal Object(the dependency is here)

```
#import "Animal.h"

@interface Dog : Animal

-(void) bark;

@end
```

Here are two screenshots showing more details, as you can see, I have two targets for each library within the same project:

[image]
[image]

However, when I link against both libraries in the sample app, I got an error saying Animal.h file not found. If I include Animal.h in libDog.a, the error will become duplicate interface definition. I am wondering how can I make this work? Thank you.